# spliting urls and geting new ones

Tags: python, regex, url

I have a huge lists o urls like this :

```
https://www.example1.com/var1/var2/var3/
https://www.example2.com/var1/var2/var3/var4
https://www.example4.com/var1/
```

and I want to be able to extract only the first two elements of the paths if there is more than 2 elements in the path section.

like this:

```
https://www.example1.com/var1/var2/
https://www.example2.com/var1/var2/
https://www.example4.com/var1/
```

I'm using python and I know that I should use Regex but the code that I have tried is not giving me what I want.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried in your question as well so that we can see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use a list comprehension with a `split` and getting the first five splits:

```
print(['/'.join(i.split('/')[:5]) for i in l])]
```

Output:

```
['https://www.example1.com/var1/var2', 'https://www.example2.com/var1/var2', 'https://www.example4.com/var1/']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split("/", 5)` with `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
s =  ['https://www.example1.com/var1/var2/var3/', 'https://www.example2.com/var1/var2/var3/var4', 'https://www.example4.com/var1/']

for i in s:
    print( "/".join(i.split("/", 5)[:-1]) )
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.example1.com/var1/var2
https://www.example2.com/var1/var2
https://www.example4.com/var1
```